# Printing only print output with SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm trying to use SML/NJ, and I use `sml < source.sml` to run the code, but it prints out too much information.

For example, this is the `source.sml`:

```
fun fac 0 = 1
  | fac n = n * fac (n - 1)
val r = fac 10 ;
print(Int.toString(r));
```

This is the output:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.77 [built: Tue Mar 10 07:03:24 2015]
- val fac = fn : int -> int
val r = 3628800 : int
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
3628800val it = () : unit
```

From [Suppress "val it" output in Standard ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265171/suppress-val-it-output-in-standard-ml), [How to disable SMLNJ warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186848/how-to-disable-smlnj-warnings), and [SMLNJ want to remove "val it = () : unit" from every print statement execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434592/smlnj-want-to-remove-val-it-unit-from-every-print-statement-execution), I got some hints how to suppress them.

I execute `CM_VERBOSE=false sml < $filename` and added one line of `Control.Print.out := {say=fn _=>(), flush=fn()=>()};` in the code, but I still have some message:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.77 [built: Tue Mar 10 07:03:24 2015]
- 3628800
```

How can I print out only the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sml` command is intended to be used interactively. It sounds to me like you would be better off building a standalone executable from your program instead.

There are a few options:

1. If you are relying on SML/NJ extensions, or if you simply cannot use another ML implementation, you can follow the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053149/sml-nj-how-to-compile-standalone-executable) to build an SML/NJ heap image that can be turned into a standalone executable using [heap2exec](http://smlnj.org/doc/heap2exec/index.html).
2. A better option might be to use the [MLton](http://mlton.org/) compiler, another implementation of Standard ML. It lacks a REPL, but unlike SML/NJ it requires no boilerplate to generate a standalone executable. Building is as simple as issuing:

   ```
   $ mlton your-program.sml
   $ ./your-program
   3628800
   ```